# Make an image contour black and white using open CV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to paint part of an image as black and white using OpenCV2 and Python3. This is the code I'm trying:

```
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h),0,0)
sub_face = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
# apply a gaussian blur on this new recangle image
# sub_face = cv2.GaussianBlur(sub_face,(9, 9), 30, borderType = 0)
sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# merge this blurry rectangle to our final image
result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1]] = sub_face
```

When I apply the GaussianBlur method, it works properly, but when I try the cvtColor method it fails with a message (on the last line): could not broadcast input array from shape (268,182) into shape (268,182,3). What am I doing wrong?

The ***c*** variable in first line is a contour (from motion detection).

I'm new into Python and OpenCV.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a single channel that results from your `cv2.cvtColor` call to three channels at once as `result_frame` is a RGB / three channel image.  You are probably wanting to assign the single channel to all three channels.  One way to do this cleanly is to exploit [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by creating a singleton channel in the third dimension, then broadcasting the result over all channels.  Since you are using the `cv2` interface to OpenCV, the native datatype used for manipulating images is a NumPy array:

```
# merge this blurry rectangle to our final image
result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1]] = sub_face[:,:,None]
```

The `:` operation in this context accesses all values in a particular dimension.  In this case, we want the first and second dimensions.  Therefore, `sub_face[:,:,None]` will make your single channel image 3D with the third dimension being a singleton (i.e. 1).  Using NumPy broadcasting will then **broadcast** this single channel image to all channels simultaneously.

Note that I didn't have to explicitly access the third dimension when assigning to `result_frame`.  That is because `result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1]]` and `result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1],:]` are the same thing as dropping indexing after the last dimension you specify implicitly assumes `:`.

Answer (score 0):

You converted sub_face to a single channel image, but result_frame is a 3 channel image.

In the last line you are trying to assign a single channel array to a 3 channel slice.

You could do this:

```
result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1], 0] = sub_face
result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1], 1] = sub_face
result_frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1], 2] = sub_face
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured out from the error message :)
But, I'm new in both Python and OpenCV, so not sure how to do this.